# Puppeteer: memory leak error and timeout handling

Tags: javascript, node.js, puppeteer

I am trying to scrape the data from this [site](https://excise.wb.gov.in/CHMS/Public/Page/CHMS_Public_Hospital_Bed_Availability.aspx). Below is the code, which is working for single district and hospital type but break when I put it in the loop. I tried putting the statements inside `getData` function to be async await but it still opens hundreds of browser instances leading to memory leak problems. How do I fix it so that it runs one at a time instead of all at once.

```
const puppeteer = require('puppeteer');
const districtList = ["020", "001", "003", "008", "016", "017", "004", "006", "005", "007", "022", "021", "019", "009",
  "012", "013", "023", "010", "002", "011", "014", "015", "018"];
outputJsonArray = [];
const url = "https://excise.wb.gov.in/CHMS/Public/Page/CHMS_Public_Hospital_Bed_Availability.aspx";

async function scrape(did, hospType) {
  // const browser = await puppeteer.launch({headless: false, args: ['--auto-open-devtools-for-tabs']});
  const browser = await puppeteer.launch({headless: false});
  const page = await browser.newPage();
  page.setDefaultNavigationTimeout(0);
  await page.goto(url, {waitUntil: 'networkidle0', timeout: 0});
  await page.waitForSelector('#ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_ddl_District');
  await page.click(hospType);
  await page.select('#ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_ddl_District', did);
  await page.waitForSelector('tbody tr');
  // extracting information from code
  let outputData = await page.evaluate(() => {
    let output = [];
    let dataRows = document.body.querySelectorAll("tbody tr");
    let cityName = document.querySelector("#ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_ddl_District").selectedOptions[0].textContent.trim();
    console.log(cityName)
    // return dataRows.length;
    console.log("Num entries == " + dataRows.length);
    dataRows.forEach((dataRow) => {
      let rowJson = {};
      // debugger;
      rowJson["Name"] = dataRow.querySelector('h5').textContent.trim().replace(/\s+/g, ' ');
      // let h3 = dataRow.querySelectorAll('li h3.text-success')[3].textContent;
      rowJson["Contact"] = dataRow.querySelector('.rounded-pill.bg-success').textContent.trim().replace(/\s+/g, ' ');      
      output.push(rowJson);
    })
    return output;
  });
  outputJsonArray = outputJsonArray.concat(outputData);
  console.log("data == ");
  console.log(outputData);
  await browser.close();
};

districtList.forEach(getData);
async function getData(districtId) {
  await scrape(districtId, "[for=ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_rdo_Govt_Flag_0]")
  await scrape(districtId, "[for=ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_rdo_Govt_Flag_1]")
  await scrape(districtId, "[for=ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_rdo_Govt_Flag_2]")
  console.log("+++++++++++++++++Full JSON below+++++++++++++++++");
  console.log(outputJsonArray);
}
```

Further, at line 17, `waitForSelector` timeouts and halts the execution completely. This is because there are some cases for which no results are available. For example, selecting "ALIPURDUAR" in district and 2nd hospital type does not return any results, therefore it keeps waiting and is supposed to timeout. How do I handle these two issues?

> (node:50036) MaxListenersExceededWarning: Possible EventEmitter memory
> leak detected. 11 exit listeners added to [process]. Use
> emitter.setMaxListeners() to increase limit (Use `node --trace-warnings ...` to show where the warning was created) (node:50036) MaxListenersExceededWarning: Possible EventEmitter memory
> leak detected. 11 SIGINT listeners added to [process]. Use
> emitter.setMaxListeners() to increase limit (node:50036)
> MaxListenersExceededWarning: Possible EventEmitter memory leak
> detected. 11 SIGTERM listeners added to [process]. Use
> emitter.setMaxListeners() to increase limit (node:50036)
> MaxListenersExceededWarning: Possible EventEmitter memory leak
> detected. 11 SIGHUP listeners added to [process]. Use
> emitter.setMaxListeners() to increase limit

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend more reliable solution: for every district and hospital run a [child process which imports puppeteer](https://devforth.io/blog/how-to-simply-workaround-ram-leaking-libraries-like-puppeteer-universal-way-to-fix-ram-leaks-once-and-forever/). In this way main process will never leak, and each child process might leak but you don't care because you kill it ASAP and it releases all resources. I know it is not documented but it solves the issue very well.

Another links:

- [original memory leak GitHub issue in puppeteer and proove that child process solves it](https://github.com/puppeteer/puppeteer/issues/5893)
- [source code of scriptimate tool which spawns a new process for every frame of animation](https://github.com/devforth/scriptimate/blob/master/bin/puWorker.js#L22)

Answer (score 0):

You're probably getting errors in the browser context. Try optional chaining and see if that helps:

```
let data = await page.$$eval('tbody tr', trs => trs.map(tr => {
  return {
    name: tr.querySelector('h5')?.textContent?.trim()?.replace(/\s+/g, ' '),
    contact: tr.querySelector('.rounded-pill.bg-uccess')?.textContent?.trim().replace(/\s+/g, ' ')
  }
}))
```

**EDIT**

So to run these one at a time you might do something like:

```
async function run(districtList){
  for(let districtId of districtList){
    await getData(districtId)
  }
}

run(districtList)
```

The problem was with forEach which looks like a for loop but isn't.

Comment: not sure how will this solve problem related to hundreds of browser instances opening simultaneously

Comment: There's nothing in the code you posted that would cause that.

Comment: No but I'm guessing that browser context errors are preventing it from getting to the `browser.close()`. You should be seeing that in stderr though

Comment: i have not even reached that point. as soon as i run the script it opens number of browser instances. each run takes about 5 minutes at least, so what you are saying should be happening after 5 min and not instantly

Comment: Sorry I misunderstood what you were asking. Please check my update.